# access the jaxb2 marshaller in endpoint handler (spring ws)

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am using Spring-WS 1.5. I have the following configuration in my spring-servlet.xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd                                                 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd                                                       
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.mypackage"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <constructor-arg ref="jaxbmarshaller"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jaxbmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                        <value>com.test.myclass1</value>
                        <value>com.test.myclass2</value>
                </list>
        </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="endpointMapping" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>
            </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

The 'GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter' is unmarshalling the request and marshalling the response with this configuration and working as expected. However, I would like to marshal the request within my endpoint method handler and would like to access the marshaller. How do I access the marshaller. Do I have access to the one supplied to the GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter.

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint {

        private static final String NAMESPACE_URI =  "http://www.test.org/9";

        @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "RequestData")
        public JAXBElement<ResponseType> myEndpointHandler(JAXBElement<RequestType> request) {
            /* how do I access the marshaller here to marshal the request */
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire it:

```
@Service
public class MarshallingServiceImpl implements MarshallingService{

    @Autowired
    private Jaxb2Marshaller jaxbmarshaller;

    @Override
    public String marshal(Entity entity) {
        StringResult marshalled = new StringResult();
        jaxbmarshaller.marshal(entity, marshalled);
        return marshalled.toString();
    }

}
```